# Google OAuth, ruby, heroku, The page you were looking for doesn't exist. But in the rails server, it worked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, oauth

I finally push my application to Heroku. It worked in the rails server ( rails s ) but in the Heroku server, it says "The page you were looking for doesn't exist. " The function is "google login". When I click the login button, it is supposed to be redirected to the login screen ( allowing us to select which Google account we will use )

In Google console, I put XXXXX.herokuapp.com in Redirect urls section with localhost:3000, localhost:5000 as well and also in Javascript origins.

When I ran heroku log, it says

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/auth/google_oauth2"):
```

I saw many similar questions but not about google oauth2 issue.
I hope that this is just routes.rb issue. I here put my routes.rb file!

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'mother/home'

  #get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  get 'auth/google_oauth2/callback', to: 'sessions#create'

  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  get 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'

  get "demo/index"
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => :get

  get "home/index"
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => :get


  resources :sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resource :home, only: [:show]

  #root to: "home#hello"
  root to: "home#front"

end
```

And this is omniauth.rb file

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx', {client_options: {ssl: {ca_file: Rails.root.join("cacert.pem").to_s}}}
end
```

This is my Gemfile.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'

gem 'puma'

group :production do 
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
#   gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', '~> 0.2.1'

end


gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'


gem "omniauth-google-oauth2", "~> 0.2.1"


# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

And this is Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    actionview (4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    activejob (4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.1)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (6.0.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (5.1.11)
      execjs
      json
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (3.3.4.1)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.0.0.1)
      sass (>= 3.2.19)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (5.0.0)
      columnize (= 0.9.0)
    coffee-rails (4.1.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
    columnize (0.9.0)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.5.2)
    faraday (0.9.1)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    globalid (0.3.5)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    hashie (3.4.1)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.2.16)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.0.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.2)
    jwt (1.5.0)
    loofah (2.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    mime-types (2.5)
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    minitest (5.6.1)
    multi_json (1.11.0)
    multi_xml (0.5.5)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    oauth2 (1.0.0)
      faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.10)
      jwt (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (~> 1.2)
    omniauth (1.2.2)
      hashie (>= 1.2, < 4)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.2.6)
      omniauth (> 1.0)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.1)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.3.0)
      oauth2 (~> 1.0)
      omniauth (~> 1.2)
    pg (0.18.2)
    puma (2.11.3)
      rack (>= 1.1, < 2.0)
    rack (1.6.1)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.1)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.1)
      activerecord (= 4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.1)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.4)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
    railties (4.2.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rdoc (4.2.0)
    sass (3.4.13)
    sass-rails (5.0.3)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    spring (1.3.6)
    sprockets (3.1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.3.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.7.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    web-console (2.1.2)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  autoprefixer-rails
  bootstrap-sass
  byebug
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  omniauth-google-oauth2 (~> 0.2.1)
  pg
  puma
  rails (= 4.2.1)
  rails_12factor
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  spring
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)
```

And this is my initilizers.

Comment: Are you sure the `omniauth-google-oauth2` gem is installed on heroku? Try running `$ heroku run rake middleware`  - it should output `use OmniAuth::Builder` somewhere near the end. Also is your `omniauth.rb` located in `/config/initializers`? And i'm guessing you mean `config/routes.rb` not `router.rb`?

Comment: Hi~ I ran : heroku run rake middleware , but I didn't get what you said.  I located omniauth.rb in initializers. ( I copied and pasted it there ).  I installed the omiiauth-google-oauth2 gem in rails but not sure how to add gem on heroku. I can see my Gemfile.lock having  the "omniauth-google-oauth2 (~> 0.2.1) in dependencies section and Gemfile having "gem 'omini~~' Would you help me out :(

Comment: So no `use OmniAuth::Builder` in the output? Or you did not understand me?

Comment: no "use omniauth::builder in the output. :(

Comment: I understand you!! :)~

Comment: Heroku installs the gems in gemfile when you push - provided that they are either outside of any groups or in the `:production` group.  You can test by `running heroku run rails c` and then type `OmniAuth` into the console. If it says `uninitialized constant OmniAuth` then the issue is with the Gemfile. Otherwise the issue may be with your initializer file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78357/discussion-between-sungpah-lee-and-papirtiger).

Comment: I have the same question like yours, have you figured it out?